# (Design Idea) Best Practise to reserve record for multi-process workflow engine

Tags: java, oracle

I'm designing multiple process to query job from database.

Each job wake up once per minute to query task and send to workflow system.

I need advice about which best way to mask record and query it and not duplicate with other process.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, depending on version:

10g and down -- use Advanced Queuing.  Have your job dequeue the keys that you've had enqueued.

11g and up -- if you don't want the hassle of queuing, you can use the `SKIP LOCKED` clause and have your job `SELECT FOR UPDATE` the task it's to work on; think of it as queuing without having to make PL/SQL calls.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have control over the database design, wouldn't you just include flag of some kind? You could just have a yes/no kind of flag, which might be too basic (?). Alternatively a more detailed approach that recorded the identity of the process which "has" the Record / Job.  This would give you a richer set of data and a more flexible application.

Comment: I assume that
1. I  should update only 200 record to flag as ProcessA .


2. I select only flag process A to process.

What is best query for that?